# Permission Denied for Foreign Server

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-fdw

I'm trying to set up a user with limited permissions that would be able to create foreign tables. I have two databases, `hr_db` and `accounting_db`. I have created an `hr_user` user for `hr_db` and a `accounting_user` user for `accounting_db`. I only want the `accounting_user` user to have select rights on some `hr_db` tables, such as the `users` table. To do this, as a superuser I went to the `hr_db` database and ran:

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE hr_db TO accounting_user;
GRANT SELECT ON people TO accounting_user;
```

I set up a connection to `hr_db` from `accounting_db` using a foreign data wrapper:

```
CREATE SERVER hr_db FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
OPTIONS (host 'localhost', dbname 'hr_db', port '5432');
```

I then added a mapping for the `accounting_user` user:

```
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR accounting_user SERVER hr_db
OPTIONS (user 'accounting_user', password 'secretpassword');
```

The password for `accounting_user` is the same as the one I use to log in from the command line. This works fine:

```
psql -U accounting_user -W hr_db
[enter accounting_user password]
SELECT * FROM people LIMIT 10;
```

I can create a regular table in the `accounting_db` database as the `accounting_user` user:

```
psql -U accounting_user -W accounting_db
[enter accounting_user password]
CREATE TABLE test (person_id integer NOT NULL);
DROP TABLE test;
```

But if I try to create a foreign table:

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE hr_people (person_id integer NOT NULL)
SERVER hr_db OPTIONS (table_name 'people');
ERROR:  permission denied for foreign server hr_db
```

As a superuser, I can create the `hr_people` foreign table and the `accounting_user` will have access to it. So the foreign data connection to `hr_db` seems correct. What else do I need to give the `accounting_user` in order for it to be able to create and drop foreign tables?

Answer (score 16):

To grant permissions for the foreign server:

```
GRANT USAGE ON FOREIGN SERVER hr_db TO accounting_user;
```

More details available in the example on official page https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/contrib-dblink-connect.html

Comment: That helped with permission denied but I am getting `ERROR:  only superuser can change options of a file_fdw foreign table` now… ☹️

Comment: > That helped with permission denied but I am getting ERROR: only superuser can > change options of a file_fdw foreign table now… 
You need to connect on *targetdb* with superuser and after grant usage